# Force outlook's e-mail correspondences into to one file

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I'm mail corresponding with a person and we both use reply (the topic remains the same) to answer I'm always getting the new correspondence in a different email/file. When we are talking about dozens of replays a mass of redundant mail is created. How do I Force MS outlook's 2010 email correspondences into to one file ?

A good example for the desired situation is in Gmail where email conversations are grouped together by default.

Secondly if the person I'm corresponding with changes the subject or don't use reply to answer me how can I merge this correspondences with other email(s) which for me discuss on the same topic ? (I tried drag & drop but it didn't work)

Thanks

Comment: You don't mean "file" of course. You probably mean "message". Outlook stores all of it's messages in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Try arranging your Inbox by "Conversation".

One way to do this is to click on the headers (where it probably says "Arranged By: Date") and choose the "Conversation" option.

Comment: Yes I meant message of course but arranging my mailbox by conversation would not solve this problem since every reply will still create a new message not merging with the previous one thus creating a lot of redundant messages. Gmail's message handling is a good example to what I want on my MS Outlook. Any other suggestions ?